# How to run a Play application on my local machine and let someone else access it from the Internet

Tags: playframework

My Play application defines a few callbacks (URLs) to be called by third party systems... and I need to test them.

Is it possible to run a Play application on a local machine and let someone else access it from the Internet? I know, I could deploy my application to Heroku... but it takes up to 30 minutes and this is not the best option when one needs to debug, fix possible bugs, and redeploy the application many times.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you need to use external IP address and also make sure that your firewall forwards external traffic to your computer (also allow that on firewall if required)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **ngrok** : https://ngrok.com/

Once installed, open a terminal, type **./ngrok 9000** and then you can access your play running on your computer at something like http://123456.ngrok.com

Answer (score 0):

You could just open the port in your router, then your application would be available at [your-ip]:9000 (or whatever port you use with play).